# Passing parameters to gradle build script

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, closures, build.gradle

I'm trying to execute a such command in the console:

```
./gradlew cucumber -Pthreads=80 -Ptags=@ALL_API_TESTS
```

in the build.gradle:

```
cucumber {
    threads = "$threads"
    glue = 'classpath:com.sixtleasing.cucumber.steps'
    plugin = ['pretty']
    tags = "$tags"
    featurePath = 'src/main/resources/feature'
    main = 'cucumber.api.cli.Main'
}
```

but it doesnt work :( How can I fix it?

Comment: what do you mean "it doesn't work" : any error / stacktrace?

Comment: It is executed only one thread. If I add 80 threads to gradle.build it works

Comment: It should work as you have written. Could you try with `threads = project.findProperty("threads") `?

Comment: You can also try `project.threads` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your original expression set threads to a `String` value, when it is clearly a numeric one, so you need to use something like:

```
int threadsNum = "$threads".toInteger()
cucumber {
    threads = threadsNum
    glue = 'classpath:com.sixtleasing.cucumber.steps'
    plugin = ['pretty']
    tags = "$tags"
    featurePath = 'src/main/resources/feature'
    main = 'cucumber.api.cli.Main'
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Grade doesnt accept it :( I got FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. and exception is in the line "$threads".toInteger()